# How do I play a sound for each element in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio

This is what I have so far. It creates an array of random numbers between 1-4. But instead of playing the audio in sequence. It plays all 4 sounds immediately. If I change the `audio` variable to play a single sound on every run of the `for` loop, it only plays the sound once.

How can I play a sound for each item in the array? Or could you tell me what I may be doing wrong.

```
var level = 5
var myArray = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < level; i++) {
        myArray.push(getRandomInt(1,4));
    }


for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

    var audio = new Audio( 'sounds/' + myArray[i] + '.wav');
    audio.play();
}
```

****UPDATE****

So I've figured out how to play them one after another in sequence. But I can't figure out how to play the sounds according to the number in the array.

```
var level = 5
var myArray = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < level; i++) {
        myArray.push(getRandomInt(1,4));
    }

var audio0 = new Audio( 'sounds/blank.wav');
var audio1 = new Audio( 'sounds/1.wav');
var audio2 = new Audio( 'sounds/2.wav');
var audio3 = new Audio( 'sounds/3.wav');
var audio4 = new Audio( 'sounds/4.wav');

audio0.play();
audio0.addEventListener('ended', function(){ audio1.play();} )
audio1.addEventListener('ended', function(){ audio2.play();} )
audio2.addEventListener('ended', function(){ audio3.play();} )
audio3.addEventListener('ended', function(){ audio4.play();} )
```

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended_(Web_Audio)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was able to figure out how to get the sounds to play one after another. But having trouble playing the sounds according to the numbers in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setTimeout instead of a for loop:

```
var i     = 0;
var audio = new Audio( 'sounds/' + myArray[i] + '.wav');
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {

    audio.play();
    if( ++i < myArray.length ) {
        // after playing, reset audio and immediately return
        // to prevent the timeout from clearing.
        audio = new Audio( 'sounds/' + myArray[i] + '.wav');        
        return;
    } 

    // clear the timeout when you run out of clips to play.
    clearTimeout(timeout);

   // audio.duration is in seconds, so multiply by 1000 to get the
   // duration in milliseconds
}, audio.duration * 1000);
```

Comment: This way it plays only the first sound.